# Why does jQuery have to connect properties of future elements to a user based event, as opposed to it just listening and actioning?

Tags: jquery

I'm really at the end of my tether on this one. For the last few weeks I have bumped into this issue continuously and I'm starting to wonder why this isn't a really basic aspect of jQuery.

All i want is for jQuery to listen for future elements and do things to them.

*But*

Without me having to correspond it to *any* events!

.live() wants an event to do things.

Surely there is something like live but where i can just say:

```
$('div').live(function() {
    //just do stuff to current and future elements 
    //without me having to initiate it with events
});
```

The reason for needing this is that i have posts being dynamically loaded via another *javascript* file. If it was jQuery, i could just listen to it and give an event.

[This](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js) is the javascript file that loads the new content.
[This](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.syndex.js) is the jquery file where I need to add the behaviour.

---

Edit: it's for this site http://syndex.me But i don't think it's totally needed for the question. Cheers

=======

Comment: Can't you just attach it to the load event?

Comment: You mean upon an elements dynamic creation, do something?

Comment: I'll +1 you for the case where you want plugins to apply to dynamically added elements, but think about this; jQuery (or the browser, etc) doesn't know when to fire the event.

Comment: Take a look at the livequery plugin.

Comment: @Joseph I think you have a point there. Is it possible to trigger a function when something starts loading on the page? That's all I'd need! Can i do something like `if new content loads into the document, do something`?

Comment: @RGBK Sounds like you're looking for the [DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument) or [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) event.  Be very careful when using these, however.  It's generally advised to avoid them altogether.  Also, if you do use them, remove the event listener when whatever code you need done is completed if at all possible; it will make the page run slow.

Comment: Joseph i think you are onto soemthing there. Searching for these gives me a series of questions just like mine. I cant stop the function though as in theory 1000s of posts could load, ten at a time. Also found this one, what do you think? `$(document).bind('change', docChanged) ;` Maybe you could turn your comment into an answer so i can upload an d potentially tick it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

But, you need some event to trigger the action.  If you just did something like this:

```
$('div').live(function() {
```

it's not associated with any action or condition or event.  When should it ever be triggered?  All event handlers must have some specified trigger or event.

If, what you're asking for is an event when an object first appears in the DOM, that event does not exist in browsers.  What you have to do instead is trigger code after elements are added to the page (often on the success handler of Ajax calls) and examine the new content in the page at that time.

---

It looks like you've added some more info to your question that says you want to know when some other script has changed your page.  That is not something that is supported by any browser.  Your choices are as follows:

1. Listen to an existing event (click, mouse, etc...) that indicates a relevant change did take place or might have taken place.
2. Use some existing notification scheme built into the code that is modifying the page (if such a thing exists).
3. Modify the script that changes the page to call you so you can do your additional work at the right time.
4. Poll the page with a timer looking for new content.

Comment: I clarified the question a little. Thing is the event is being triggered by a javascript file elsewhere, hence i can't attach live to any event, so what can one do in that situation?

Comment: I added a few more comments to my answer based on your new info.

Comment: Thanks jFriend. Can you look at that script that adds the content? It's an ugly beast. Thing is, it's also the only known or widely used infinite scroll script for tumblr (others don't work, viva tumblr). I have actually managed to make it call a ajax spinner for loads at the functions addNextPage (line 204) and watch_scroll (line 229). The thing is, I can only do stuff with elements i create in that file. Any page native objects are at least for me, impossible to reference in this file, I keep getting errors. http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.syndex.js

Comment: Unless... is it possible to suddenly inject jquery coding in the place i need the thing action to happen in a javascript file? Simular to the way you can inject php in html? Then I could do an ".each()" whenever there are new instances of the element i need to tweek?!

Comment: @RGBK - Sorry, but I don't really follow what event and objects you're trying to intercept.

Comment: 3. Modify the script that changes the page to call you so you can do your additional work at the right time. — I thought this wasnt possible though? How can the javascript file call the jquery file? If it were possible this would be amazing.

Comment: Going with route 3 and 4, I've asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985249/possible-when-a-function-in-a-javascript-file-is-triggered-it-lets-a-function Thanks.