# Possible? When a function in a javascript file is triggered, it lets a function in a jQuery file know?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

Could I create a function or custom event in a javascript file called "justDidStuff" and then make .live() watch for that being triggered in another jQuery file?

I know this sounds really complicated, but I can't think of another way to do this.

I have new content coming in from the javascript file which is the *only* infinite scroller known to work for Tumblr.

I have a bunch of styling happening on the layout of the incoming posts (http://syndex.me) which i'm obviously going to make with jQuery. Hence i'm in a situation where I

A) have to use .live() (posts are dynamically loaded) and 
B) can't trigger the changes in a straightforward manner

In a previous question related to this `DOMNodeInserted` was reluctantly suggested. This just listens for when something has been changed, but it slows down pages such as this and has been depreciated.

---

EDIT

http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js
Is the javascript file (NB it's a monster)

http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.syndex.js
Is my Styling and Site behaviour jQuery file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind` and `trigger`.

```
var justDidStuff = function(){
    //do some stuff
}

$('something').bind('justDidStuff',justDidStuff); // binds to all elements, 
                                                  // now and in the future.

//call it:
$('something').trigger('justDidStuff');
```

Comment: question, when you say 'now and in the future' does it mean it works for stuff that you add later?  or would you need to use .live instead for that to happen?

Comment: cool, why is it different than like when you bind a click event?  because you manually call it with .trigger so it checks elements at that point instead of when you do .bind?

Comment: You can use `bind` for any type of event. It does not have to be a mouse or keyboard event.

Comment: Does this solve the problem though? I'm still stuck with a jquery event `trigger`. I need the javacript file to trigger the `justDidStuff` function. I get this: `$('something').bind('justDidStuff',justDidStuff);` But then that has to listen for it being triggered in the javascript file. Makes sense? I will edit the question to show the two files in question. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Something like this:

```
jQuery("body").bind("myEvent", function( data ){ alert("triggered"); } );
```

and in your function you can notify the page

```
jQuery("body").trigger("myEvent", { "foo", "bar" });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved the problem. It's so easy i can't believe it. You live and learn. All I had to do was place jquery code inline within the javascript file by doing this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {//doStuff in a javascript file as normal, OMG}
```